# UEFI runtime services gRT->SetTime(&Time) does not sync with the operating system time

Tags: linux, clock, uefi

I have implemented a time config form browser on UEFI to enable users to set the time. However, I am not able to get the same time I set in the UEFI browser when I boot to the Linux operating system.

In my edk2 code, I've implemented logic to take a string input from the keyboard in the UEFI browser. It then processed the input time using `gRT->SetTime(&Time)`. I printed out debug messages to make sure I got the time I just set running correctly after I come back again to the same form. However, I exited UEFI and booted to the operating system, command `date` showed me the time before I did the configuration in UEFI.

Both the original time and the time I set did not have the time zone value set (kept at 2047).

The gRT->SetTime(&Time) runtime services call did not synchronize with the operating system. What did I miss here?

Comment: Is your linux configured to snyc with an ntp server? When you reset the system, are you getting the correct time from gRT->GetTime()?

Comment: Yes. I did not realize there is an auto-update via the ntp server. Thanks!